# How to print what is in between a certain number of backslashes (Perl)

Tags: perl

I have a url that looks similar to

```
//google.com/Ucomm/Photos/1984 Digital Photos/blah blah/Reflections Magazine/Fall 1984    issue/This is what I want 7-28/TMI_7840_xx.PNG
```

Each URL is different but I want the same part out of it which would be the part right before the filename.
I figured if I counted the number of backslashes I could print what's in between  the second to the last one and the last one..

So the output would look like

```
This is what I want 7-28
```

What I have so far counts the number of backslashes but I am not sure how to print what I need.

The Code:

```
my $string = $cells[74];
my $count = lc($string) =~ tr/\///;
print $count;
```

Comment: I see no backslashes, Windowsboy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need to count slashes (and those are forward slashes, not backslashes), just start at the end and work backwards.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $string = "//google.com/Ucomm/Photos/1984 Digital Photos/blah blah/Reflections Magazine/Fall 1984    issue/This is what I want 7-28/TMI_7840_xx.PNG";

say "Version 1";
{
        my @parts = split '/', $string;
        say $parts[-2];
}

say "Version 2"; # if you love regular expressions
{
        my ($captured) = $string =~ m!/([^/]+)/[^/]+$!;
        say $captured;
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly... I had to use print instead of say becuase of a weird error.. but Regular expressions are crazy...

Comment: @David Did you forget to `use v5.10` or `use feature qw(say)`? `say` is not a core function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `basename` and `dirname` for that:

```
use File::Basename;

my $str="//google.com/Ucomm/Photos/1984 Digital Photos/blah blah/Reflections Magazine/Fall 1984    issue/This is what I want 7-28/TMI_7840_xx.PNG";

print basename(dirname($str));
```

Alternatively, `split` the string on `/` and take the before-last element.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [split](http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/Perl/split.html)

```
my @data = split('/', $string);
print $data[-2];
```

Comment: That would get the data between the first and second slash, not between the penultimate and last slash.

Comment: And using a regular expression when you are splitting on a single character is just messy.

Comment: `split` always treats the first argument as a regular expression

Answer (score 0):

Break the input into an array. The question is: How do identify the field you want?  By position?

```
    #!/usr/bin/env perl

    use strict;
    use warnings;

    use Data::Dumper;

    # Make Data::Dumper pretty
    $Data::Dumper::Sortkeys = 1;
    $Data::Dumper::Indent   = 1;

    # Set maximum depth for Data::Dumper, zero means unlimited
    local $Data::Dumper::Maxdepth = 0;

    my $string = '//google.com/Ucomm/Photos/1984 Digital Photos/blah blah/Reflections Magazine/Fall 1984    issue/This is what I want 7-28/TMI_7840_xx.PNG';

    my @array = split /\//, $string;
    print Dumper \@array;

__END__
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression:

```
if ($str=~/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$/) {
   print "$1\n"
} else {
   print "ERROR\n"
}
```

Example:

```
perl -e '$str="google.com/Ucomm/Photos/1984 Digital Photos/blah blah/Reflections Magazine/Fall 1984    issue/This is what I want 7-28/TMI_7840_xx.PNG"; if ($str=~/([^\/]*)\/([^\/]*)$/) {print "$1\n"} else {print "ERROR\n"}'

This is what I want 7-28
```